# Connecting to Cassandra with Spark

Tags: cassandra, apache-spark, cassandra-2.0

First, I have bought the new O'Reilly Spark book and tried those Cassandra setup instructions. I've also found other stackoverflow posts and various posts and guides over the web. None of them work as-is. Below is as far as I could get.

This is a test with only a handful of records of dummy test data. I am running the most recent Cassandra 2.0.7 Virtual Box VM provided by plasetcassandra.org linked from the main Cassandra project page.

I downloaded Spark 1.2.1 source and got the latest Cassandra Connector code from github and built both against Scala 2.11. I have JDK 1.8.0_40 and Scala 2.11.6 setup on Mac OS 10.10.2.

I run the spark shell with the cassandra connector loaded:

```
bin/spark-shell --driver-class-path ../spark-cassandra-connector/spark-cassandra-connector/target/scala-2.11/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly-1.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Then I do what should be a simple row count type test on a test table of four records:

```
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
sc.stop
val conf = new org.apache.spark.SparkConf(true).set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "192.168.56.101")
val sc = new org.apache.spark.SparkContext(conf)
val table = sc.cassandraTable("mykeyspace", "playlists")
table.count
```

I get the following error. What is confusing is that it is getting errors trying to find Cassandra at 127.0.0.1, but it also recognizes the host name that I configured which is 192.168.56.101.

```
15/03/16 15:56:54 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /192.168.56.101:9042 added
15/03/16 15:56:54 INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: Cluster on a Stick
15/03/16 15:56:54 ERROR ServerSideTokenRangeSplitter: Failure while fetching splits from Cassandra
java.io.IOException: Failed to open thrift connection to Cassandra at 127.0.0.1:9160
<snip>
java.io.IOException: Failed to fetch splits of TokenRange(0,0,Set(CassandraNode(/127.0.0.1,/127.0.0.1)),None) from all endpoints: CassandraNode(/127.0.0.1,/127.0.0.1)
```

BTW, I can also use a configuration file at conf/spark-defaults.conf to do the above without having to close/recreate a spark context or pass in the --driver-clas-path argument. I ultimately hit the same error though, and the above steps seem easier to communicate in this post.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the rpc_address config in your cassandra.yaml file on your cassandra node.  It's likely that the spark connector is using that value from the system.local/system.peers tables and it may be set to 127.0.0.1 in your cassandra.yaml.

The spark connector uses thrift to get token range splits from cassandra.  Eventually I'm betting this will be replaced as C* 2.1.4 has a new table called system.size_estimates ([CASSANDRA-7688](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7688)).  It looks like it's getting the host metadata to find the nearest host and then making the query using thrift on port 9160.